# How to show magento default backorder notice message in minicart & sales emails(same like cart page)

Tags: magento2, mini-cart, backorder, magento2minicart

Have tried looking into several blogs & stackoverflow answers but unfortunately didnt find any solutions.
I am using mage 2.4.0
Can someone please look into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For minicart in app/design/frontend//Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html I added

```
<p><!-- ko text: message --><!-- /ko --></p>
```

which appended the default backorder message, same like cart page & for sales emails, I did customization.